# ggroc and geom_density on same plot

Tags: r

I cannot seem to combine a ggroc plot and a ggplot object. I have the following data called `results` at this link.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/at2f2zni7s1hnzm/results.csv?dl=0

The code that I have;

```
roc <- roc(results$testactual, results$pred)
ggroc(roc) +
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data = results %>%
                 filter(testactual == 0), aes(pred), color='green') + 
  geom_density(data = results %>%
                 filter(testactual == 1), aes(pred), color='black')
```

Which returns an error;

`Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot`

I have followed other answers online and they don´t seem to fit in with my solution. I know it must be something with `roc` creating a large `roc` with 15 elements and trying to combine this with a plot of a `data.frame`.

Comment: please add you data using `dput()`. Can you just try `ggroc(roc) + geom_` leaving the ggplot call out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggroc calls ggplot function, so you dont have to do it:

```
roc <- roc(results$testactual, results$pred)
ggroc(roc) +
  geom_density(data = results %>%
                 filter(testactual == 0), aes(pred), color='green') + 
  geom_density(data = results %>%
                 filter(testactual == 1), aes(pred), color='black')
```